# Load angular module at runtime with/without ocLazyLoad

Tags: angularjs, dependency-injection, oclazyload, angular-module

I have a couple of modules that I am trying to load at runtime based on some conditions. Currently I am using the[ocLazyLoad](https://oclazyload.readme.io/) module but I am the loaded module's are not working at all. Everything loads fine, there are no errors being thrown.

I first declare my main module

```
var app = angular.module('myApp',['oc.lazyLoad'])

app.config(['$ocLazyLoadProvider',function(){
    modules : [{
       name : 'mod1',
       files : [CDN-Path]
     }]
}]);
```

and then somewhere in my controller

```
app.controller('c',function($ocLazyLoad){

     $ocLazyLoad.load('mod1').then(function(){
           console.log('module loaded!');
     });
})
```

What I truly do inside the resolved promise is that I register a new state with ui-router, and within that state I use some of the directives defined in `mod1`, but they simply don't work. Is there further initialization that must be performed after the module loads?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can lazy load any module/directive/controller/javascript(*jquery as well*) before view as below:

```
angular.module('app', ['ui.router', 'oc.lazyLoad']).config(['$stateProvider', '$ocLazyLoadProvider', function ($stateProvider, $ocLazyLoadProvider) {
        $ocLazyLoadProvider.config({
            modules : [{
                    name : 'TestModule',
                    files : ['js/TestModule.js', 'js/AppCtrl.js']
                }
            ]
        });

        $stateProvider.state('index', {
            url : "/", // root route
            views : {
                "lazyLoadView" : {
                    controller : 'AppCtrl', // This view will use AppCtrl loaded below in the resolve
                    templateUrl : 'partials/main.html'
                }
            },
            resolve : { // Any property in resolve should return a promise and is executed before the view is loaded
                loadMyCtrl : ['$ocLazyLoad', function ($ocLazyLoad) {
                        // you can lazy load files for an existing module
                        return $ocLazyLoad.load('TestModule');
                    }
                ]
            }
        });
    }
]);
```

https://oclazyload.readme.io/docs/with-your-router

**Edit Plunker sample with `controller` and `ui-bootstrap` lazy loaded :** https://plnkr.co/edit/pUq3b1TDkwdGQOftcWDL?p=preview

Comment: I have read this, but the issue here is not that the modules are not loading. They load and register, I can do `angular.module('mod1')` and retrieve it, the issue is that they are not being added as a dependency of the current module. To be able to add new elements that implement functionality (such as a directive) from the newly registered module

Comment: I just tried it in case I probably missed something and it responded in the same manner

Comment: I had a plunker sample, hope it should help :)